# Will react-router affect page load time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

For example, if I have 3 routes in the `routes.js` file compared to that of 10 routes in the same file. Will the file containing 10 routes take longer time to load? Supposing every route import the same size of the component. Or the component will be imported after we've enter the route?

Comment: This question is too general. Can you give more detail specific details of a problem you are trying to solve? Yes a file with more characters will take longer to download and yes a file with more logic will take longer to process. But for the numbers you are talking about (7 more routes) the difference should be trivial and irrelevant. If you are worried about the sizes of your components and having to load them all on initial page load, you should research how to make the router lazy load components.

Answer (score 0):

If you bundle your app (e.g. with webpack) and you are not lazy-loading your components, then the components itself **won't add up** to your load time. **But probably on your performance.**

But when all of your - let's say - 10 components load resources over a RESTful API, then of course your components will indeed **add up** to your load time.
This could be prevented by using `GraphQL + Relay` though.

Answer (score 0):

The first page load might be slightly longer than usual (still probably not even noticeable in most cases), but after that, the page will be entirely cached, resulting in super fast load times, since the browser will remember everything.